# ExtJS 4 - Grid - Disable rowselection for specific column

Tags: extjs, checkbox, grid, extjs4, selection

I have created a grid with extjs 4. The selection.CheckboxModel is implemented to. This means that the row is selected/deselected wherever you click on the particular row. Now i want to disable this selection on the last column since it contains custom buttons. (I don't want to select the row if a button is clicked).

Any idea's how to do this?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is actually a tricky little problem, if only because Sencha documentation is lacking.

The CheckboxModel does indeed have a `beforeselect` event inherited from `Ext.selection.RowModel`. However, there's no easy way to get the column index because frankly, that's the point of the RowModel.

However, there's an undocumented event in `Ext.view.Table` (which your grid will inherit) called `beforecellmousedown`. Here's the event parameters:

1. view: The view of your grid
2. cell: The cell that was clicked
3. cellIndex: Index of the cell
4. record: The store record associated with the cell
5. row: The row of the cell
6. rowIndex: Index of the row
7. eOpts: Standard event option event

So you would probably try something like this:

```
viewConfig: {
    listeners: {
        beforecellmousedown: function(view, cell, cellIdx, record, row, rowIdx, eOpts){
            if(cellIdx === indexOfLastColumnInGrid){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Both the cell and row indexes are zero-based.

Answer (score 1):

```
listeners: {
    beforecellmousedown: function(view, cell, cellIdx, record, row, rowIdx, eOpts) {
        if (String(eOpts.getTarget()) == '[object HTMLButtonElement]') {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanx Eric. This i the final solution!

Answer (score 0):

Read this article http://www.learnsomethings.com/2012/01/12/stopping-a-checkbox-from-allowing-select-in-an-extjs-4-grid-checkbox-column-via-the-ext-selection-checkboxmodel/
I hope it will help you.

Comment: Within the within 'beforeselect', how can i check wich column was clicked?