# Ext JS 4: grid - some action on itemclick and different action when clicked on action column

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a grid and I need clickable rows - a new window should be opened when a row is clicked. But I would like to add an action column with delete icon which would delete the row on click. The problem is that when the icon in the action column is clicked the action related to the row is also triggered and the new window is opened. I need to find a way how to trigger one action when action column is clicked and another action when the rest of the row is clicked. Any ideas please?

Maybe something like following pseudo-code:

```
grid.on('itemclick', function(grid, rowIndex, columnIndex, e) {
    if (action column clicked) { // do something }
    else { // do something else }
}, this);
```

... but how do I detect that the action column was clicked?
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
grid.on('itemclick', function(grid, rowIndex, columnIndex, e) {
    if (action column clicked) { // do something }
    else { // do something else }
}, this);
```

Use this:

```
grid.getView().on('cellmousedown',function(view, cell, cellIdx, record, row, rowIdx, eOpts){
    //itemclick logic
});
```

This event does not get fired in case of an actioncolumn. So you don't need an `if - else`

Looks like this event is undocumented, but there is a private method in the docs [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.view.Table-method-onCellMouseDown)

Reference: [ExtJS 4 - Grid - Disable rowselection for specific column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534077/extjs-4-grid-disable-rowselection-for-specific-column/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [`Ext.EventObject#stopPropagation()`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.EventObject-method-stopPropagation) or [`Ext.EventObject#stopEvent()`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.EventObject-method-stopEvent)?

You can add it inside your **action colum handler**:

`e.stopPropagation();`

This way the grid's `itemclick` event won't trigger.

Comment: Thank you but this does not seem to be working. I tried e.stopPropagation(), e.prevendDefault(), e.stopEvent(). I guess am doing something wrong: handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex, act, e) { e.stopPropagation(); }

Comment: Based on the order these events get fired this may never work. But I don't know the order, so it's just a guess. @honzzz Maybe you can store the rowclick as deferred handler so that it can be canceled by the button handler.

Comment: How about checking the columIndex: `if (columnIndex != actionColumnIndex) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

A more direct answer to your question, without having to change event type, would be:

```
grid.on('itemclick', function(grid, rowIndex, columnIndex, e) {
  var columnType = grid.panel.columns[columnIndex].xtype;
  if (columnType === 'actioncolumn') {
    // it's action column!
  } else {
    // it's NOT action column!
  }
}, this);
```